# Arduino Mega2560 clone responding slowly

Tags: arduino-mega, bootloader

I am using an Arduino Mega2560. Using Arduino Mega as ISP to burn sketch, I had loaded the bootloader from Arduino IDE.

I uploaded the blink LED code to the Mega. But the LED is responding slowly. Same with Serial code. Delay of 0.1 second acting as 1 second on my board. In code serial communication baud-rate is 9600 but I am getting proper value when I set the baud-rate to 4800 in serial monitor.

Could anyone point out the problem?

Comment: If Your Clone is slow. Then Replace it..Clones are very cheap to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Either your fuses are wrong (set to 50% the real speed of your crystal / ceramic resonator), you're using the internal oscillator instead of the expected external one, or you have the wrong board with the wrong F_CPU value selected in the IDE.

Check all of those carefully.

Comment: thanks Can you let me know the fuse values, coz i had not change any thing in boot loader. also can you let me know how to choose external or internal oscillator

Comment: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/fuse-bits-mega2560-arduino